# Is it possible to perform Bulk Insert in MSAccess

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access

Hello friend how can I perform Bulk insert into MDB from Dataset.
till now I have done something like this

```
string InsertBulkQry = "INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM table IN "       

  +MYDs.Tables[0];
```

I am using C# and VS 2005

Or is there any other way to update Ms Access table Faster with multiple records
Thanks All

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible. More Info :[INSERT INTO Statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

```
var cmdText = "INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2";
var command = new OleDbCommand(cmdText, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Not tested, it should work. Or you can create a query in Access and Execute it from C# code.

Comment: @Rohit Do you have a table1? If not, you need select into, otherwise the above sql works for me.

Comment: The example is very awful, how to insert the table2? There is no bulk insert in OleDb,

Comment: @FrankX Did you checked the documentation link?

Comment: @Anuraj I suggest you to look into the link to see what it means. The question is about "How to Insert DATASET into MSACCESS in Batch", your link just told you how you insert record, or insert record by table that is already existed in the Access, so, how you insert the data from datatable to the Access by batch?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var access = new Access.Application();
            access.OpenCurrentDatabase(@"C:\whatever.mdb");
            access.DoCmd.RunSQL("INSERT INTO Table1 SELECT * FROM Table2");
            access.CloseCurrentDatabase();

            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(access);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not use RunSQL, it produces warnings and turning warnings off is not a good idea. Furthermore, if the sql is not working against a connection, I do not see why it would work in an instance of MS Access.

Comment: @Remou I didn't think about it that way, but I agree, Anuraj's way is better!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the [MS Access INSERT SQL Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861%28v=office.12%29.aspx) explained.

Comment: Well actually I am muddled over here.The statement here says **INSERT INTO target [(field1[, field2[, …]])] [IN externaldatabase]     SELECT [source.]field1[, field2[, …]     FROM tableexpression** however I am not able to relate my values with this given epression.

Comment: What's the point of providing the same link as the previous answer, except without a summary!? (and 3mins later.)

Comment: till now my query is **string InsertBulkQry = "INSERT INTO Table1 [(Field1,[Field2,[Field3,[Field4]]])] Select [Field1],[Field2],[Field3],[Field4] from" + MyDs.Tables[0];** But no luck.Where I am going wrong?